# How to keep asking for user name and password until correct while authenticating the user in jira using python jira module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-jira

I am using python jira module. Now when the user enters the jira username and password, it is authenticated using JIRA(option,basic_auth = (username,password)).
How do I keep asking for the username or password if entered one is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the jira library,but funcmedtly,this is what it should look like:

```
username,passwd=input().split()
while not is_correct(username,passwd):
    username,passwd=input().split()
# .. Do something with username and passwd ..
```